# Ubuntu 14.04 Gstreamer autovideosink

Tags: ubuntu, gstreamer, pipeline

I am trying to get a Gstreamer video stream running on Ubuntu 14.04 but the receiver side is unable to display video properly. I have a sender pipeline sending MJPEG images which I start like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5200
```

The output is:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoTestSrc:videotestsrc0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, framerate=(fraction)30/1, format=(string)I420, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstJpegEnc:jpegenc0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, framerate=(fraction)30/1, format=(string)I420, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstJpegEnc:jpegenc0.GstPad:src: caps = image/jpeg, sof-marker=(int)0, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpJPEGPay:rtpjpegpay0.GstPad:src: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)JPEG, a-framerate=(string)30.000000, a-framesize=(string)320-240, payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)1970481773, timestamp-offset=(uint)1012832172, seqnum-offset=(uint)21614
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)JPEG, a-framerate=(string)30.000000, a-framesize=(string)320-240, payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)1970481773, timestamp-offset=(uint)1012832172, seqnum-offset=(uint)21614
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpJPEGPay:rtpjpegpay0.GstPad:sink: caps = image/jpeg, sof-marker=(int)0, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpJPEGPay:rtpjpegpay0: timestamp = 1012832172
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpJPEGPay:rtpjpegpay0: seqnum = 21614
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
```

The receive pipeline is:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5200 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)JPEG, a-framerate=(string)30.000000, a-framesize=(string)320-240, payload=(int)96" ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! xvimagesink
```

Notice I have copied the caps from the sender info.

However, I keep getting a "could not send sticky events" error, and the receiver terminates immediately. What could I be doing wrong? My output is below:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
0:00:00.016961467 12229      0x266a400 WARN                GST_PADS gstpad.c:3669:gst_pad_peer_query:<jpegdec0:src> could not send sticky events
0:00:00.017297845 12229      0x266a400 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2865:gst_base_src_loop:<udpsrc0> error: Internal data flow error.
0:00:00.017306308 12229      0x266a400 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2865:gst_base_src_loop:<udpsrc0> error: streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(2865): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0:
streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)
Execution ended after 0:00:00.000651039
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

I have tried the autovideosink, ximagesink, with the same results.

Thanks.

Comment: the sticky events I get almost all the time.. ignore it.. the real problem is - not negotiated.. it means the elements do not fully link together because they do not understand each other, I will check it on my machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey you just need to add videoconvert - the jpegdec generates video which xvimagesink does not understand:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5200 ! application/x-rtp\,\ media\=\(string\)video\,\ clock-rate\=\(int\)90000\,\ encoding-name\=\(string\)JPEG\,\ a-framerate\=\(string\)\"30\\\,000000\"\,\ payload\=\(int\)26\,\ ssrc\=\(uint\)2512101225\,\ timestamp-offset\=\(uint\)1627080146\,\ seqnum-offset\=\(uint\)4727 ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink
```

How I figured this out? by using fakesink this way:

```
udpsrc ! fakesink -v
```

worked,then

```
udpsrc ! rptjpegdepay ! fakesink
```

worked again .. so I continued like this and find out that the problem is really in xvimagesink.. Its weird that we do not get more explicit error message..

Also you can debug the app with:

```
GST_DEBUG=4 gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc .....
```

You can scroll to the part where not negotiated happened and look around.

Comment: @wireless_freedom glad to hear that :) if it solves your problem you may accept this answer by using tick under the vote number